# Python get output for a process died by SIGABRT

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sigabrt

I'm coding a simple script that executes a third party driver for a hardware and get the results back.

If I manually run the driver binary from shell, I get the desired output but the driver program die before "return 0" with the message `double free or corruption`. This is a bug on the proprietary driver running on my Linux machine probably.

Anyway, the output before this error is correct and I want to work with it. So I coded this simple script, following another StackOverflow answer:

```py
    try:
        p = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        print("OUT:", p)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERR:", e)
        print(str(e.output))
```

The expected result for me here would be a line with `OUT` string followed of the "good piece" of the stdout execution, and an `ERR` line with the error above explained. Instead, the only output I get is:

```
ERR: Command '['propetaryDriver']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
b'double free or corruption (out)\n'
```

Is any trick I can use to handle this and get both outputs?

Comment: I wouldn't use `check_output()` if I was specifically not interested in the exit status as seems to be your case. I'd use `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: Ok, this show me the stdout of the driver, but how can I don't find a way to check the strings printed line by line. Perhaps I should do something with `p`?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use this output. It seem just dummy printing and I can't interact with it